# Looking for a way to scan cylindrical objects

Tags: stepper-motor

Can anyone recommend a commercial or solid, reliable DIY solution for scanning cylindrical objects? I've seen a couple of simple hacks for flatbed scanners, but I'm looking for something I could make or buy for a commercial project that work reliably.

Many thanks

Comment: What does it mean to you for something to work reliably?  Are you looking for a certain metric of precision or repeatability?  There are many ways to do this; the question is which one will meet your needs.  What are those needs (size, simplicity, resolution, post-processing requirements, etc)?

Comment: What size are the cylindrical objects? Max, Min?

Comment: Average 750ml wine bottles and beer bottles. Not too big. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are a poor fit for a Robotics question because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: In particular what problem are you actually trying to solve? Are you trying to identify bottles? Read their bar codes? Do you need scan one label, both labels, or the whole bottle? Will the bottles be placed manually, or are they on a conveyor. What orientations might the bottles be in? What are the limitations on manipulation of the bottles? Can they be spun, rolled, shaken? Etc. etc. This is what we mean by 'unbounded'. Please edit your question with all relevant details and we can re-open it for you. Could a triplet of fixed cameras and some stitching/de-warping software do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

A company I do work for has a patented device that scans prescription bottle labels resulting in a flat image.  We have been discussing ways of scaling this up for larger cylindrical objects.  Is this still something you are interested in ?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Richard Martin, but please read [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and [How not to be a spammer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). The way this was written, it looks less like an answer and more like an advert for your Company services.